# Connect Django Amazon Lightsail Mysql

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-lightsail

Explanation: I have 2 instances of Amazon Lightsail. One has **MYSQL** and the other has **CentOs**.  I have my app Django with apache mod_wsgi, for connecting Django(instance 1) to Mysql(instance 2) using the endpoint from  Amazon:

```
ls-846d543ff0bab456d8a9309bd9585f11072f.cqaexlou8v8h.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

and I get this error:

```
(1045, u"Access denied for user 'toor'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

my settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'SERVER':'ls-846d543ff0bab456d8a9309bd9585f11072f.cqaexlou8v8h.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'toor',
        'PASSWORD': 'q1w2e3r4t5' ,
    }
}
```

I created a user using mySQL Workbench like this:

```
create user toor identified by 'q1w2e3r4t5';
grant all on my_db.* to 'toor'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

and try this code:

```
grant all on my_db.* to toor@localhost identified by 'q1w2e3r4t5' with grant option;
```

I create this user by Mysql Workbench with instance2(mysql amazon Lightsail)

please some one suggest..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was :
change **SERVER** by **HOST**:
on the setup Django only change this:

```
'SERVER':'my_server'
```

by:

```
'HOST':'my_server'
```

is very strange but with this change i can connect to my server mysql amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Where is MySQL running:

Localhost alongside Django?
An instance you hand built and installed MySQL on?
A Lightsail database instance?

My suspicion is that your `'SERVER':'host_amazon'` parameter is incorrect. As I'd expect it to either be `localhost`, the internal IP of your custom built instance, or the endpoint of your Lightsail database (something like: `ls-7d2174226335104ebdb71cfebe89d1c8f060c799.cdekwlh0imih.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`)

How did you create the user? What server did you connect to?